# Is there a way to run Get-SMBShareAccess on a large collection of SMB shares in a highly performant way?

Tags: powershell

### Problem

When using `Get-SMBShareAccess` on a large collection of SMB Shares (~10,000),
the performance degrades significantly. I would like to figure out a way to make
this go faster.

### Environment Information:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- PSVersion 5.1.14409.1018
- SmbShare module 2.0.0.0

### What I've Tried

I tried adding the `ThrottleLimit` parameter and reducing the number, with the
thought that perhaps it was running too many at once causing a problem. I also
tried batching the calls into smaller pieces but this did not seem to help.

### Code

```
$smbShares = Get-SMBShare | Where-Object { $_.Path -like "C:\MyPath" }
$smbAcls = $smbShares | Get-SMBShareAccess
```

How can I make this perform faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error, I discovered that what was making this call execute so slowly was utilizing the pipeline. Changing to a parameter based call fixed the issue.

The following code executes many times faster:

```
$smbShares = Get-SMBShare | Where-Object { $_.Path -like "C:\MyPath" }
$smbAcls = Get-SMBShareAccess -InputObject $smbShares
```

I believe this is due to something about the internal implementation of `Get-SMBShareAccess` and it's implementation of pipeline support.

Comment: Nicely done. Avoiding the pipeline is generally key to better performance, but note that it only works if a given cmdlet's pipeline-binding parameter (typically, `-InputObject`) is defined as an _array_ type - as is the case here (`CimInstance[]`), but as is _not_ typical.

Comment: You can additionally speed up the first command as follows: `$smbShares = foreach ($share in Get-SBMShare) { if ($share.Path -like 'C:\MyPath') { $share } }`. Also note that `C:\MyPath` doesn't contain any wildcard metacharacters such as `*`, so if they're truly not needed, you can use `-eq` for a further performance boost.